# what are you NOT allowed to do when solving systems of linear equations with a parameter using gauss elimination?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

since you cant multiply a row by 0, you cant do operations like: kRow2-Row1 etc what are other "rules" that you need to follow to keep your system equivalent?

Comment: If you write your system as a matrix equation $Ax=b$, then you can multiply both sides on the left by any (properly sized) invertible matrix without changing the solutions to the system. In particular, you can multiply by elementary matrices which correspond to elementary row operations (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix).

Comment: The reason you can't multiply a row by 0 is that this process is irreversible and you lose information about the system. In other words, the matrix corresponding to multiplying a row by 0 is not invertible.